# Transform if else to pattern matching in recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

For this function that counts the number of elements in a list that hold a predicate,

```
count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count _ [] = 0
count p (x:xs) = (if (p x) then 1 else 0) + count p xs
```

how to convert the `if-else` expression onto a pattern matching while preserving the summation.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you're asking, but were you looking for `count' p (x:xs) True = 1 + count' p xs (p x); count' p (x:xs) False = count' p xs (p x)`?

Comment: I don't think it's clever to switch to guards / pattern matching here. I'd write your function as `count p = length . filter p`, done. Or `count p = foldr (\x -> if p x then (+1) else id) 0`: sometimes an `if` isn't bad at all, it's certainly better than a pattern match.

Comment: @leftaroundabout agree, noticed also this comprehension `count' p xs = length [x | x <- xs, p x]` , yet would like to know this specific transformation...

Comment: @leftaroundabout ..but could also be a sign of a homework assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
count' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count' _ [] = 0
count' p (x:xs) | p x = 1 + count' p xs
count' p (x:xs) | otherwise = 0 + count' p xs
```

Comment: I would change `count' p (x:xs) | otherwise` to just `| otherwise`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert if-else to pattern matching at the level of function definition. Pattern matching is for matching a value against its constructors. `If-else`, on the other hand, tests against `True` and `False`.

By pattern matching, you can decide based on **how** a value looks like, rather than **what** the value is. To test what the value is, you use either guards or `if-else` expression.

However, you can convert it to pattern matching using a `case-of` expression:

```
count' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count' _ [] = 0
count p (x:xs) = case (p x) of
                     True  -> 1 + count' p xs
                     False -> count' p xs
```

This is pattern matching against the constructor of the `Bool` data type, which has two constructors - `True` and `False`, without any actual data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bool`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-Bool.html#bool) function from `Data.Bool` module, which does the pattern matching.

```
bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a
bool f _ False = f
bool _ t True  = t
```

So,

```
count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count _ [] = 0
count p (x:xs)  = bool 0 1 (p x) + count p xs
```